# How to use powershell with Intersystems Cache?

Tags: powershell, intersystems-cache

I'd like to use powershell as a replacement for Intersystems's Console/Terminal. Is there a way to connect to cache with powershell and issue cache commands against the server?

Comment: It would probably involve writing some PowerShell code.  Do you have some to show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache terminal is just a telnet session, so you could use telnet from powershell.

You could also do your own Read Evaluate Print Loop by connecting to Cache by any means for the Evaluate step.  Though your method of connection might make it difficult for break statements to work or for write statements (or anything else that uses a device) to work correctly.

You could also open terminal in another process and use [DDE](http://training.intersystems.com/tutorials/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GTER_advanced_topics) to drive the terminal from power shell, but that's starting to get silly.